How to troubleshoot finding a derallieur hanger?
does anyone know how to find a replacement derailleur hanger when you don't even know if the hanger is standard shape and the bike is long out of production?
Solutions requiring cutting a hanger to shape are also welcome, I have a dremel, a sortiment of filing tools and even some 2mm perforated steel plates.
This is the first time I have to replace a hanger though.
For example this one


it's from an old Kildemoes road bike (4mm thin side, 8mm thick side, 10mm frame hole with 12mm recess).
I've seen online that there are some standard shapes but I don't even know if this is one of them for example.
I have also only ever seen one Kildemoes road bike, which is this one that I bought used, so in terms of availability this one might be one of the trickiest.
EDIT:
As @Noise found, turns out this hanger is "standard" but the name of the bike manufacturer and model is not listed by any of the hanger manufacturers, being able to filter by number of fastener really helps. Because of this I kept looking and I found more hanger manufacturers with this model and a couple of website reporting the measurements so that I could confirm by size and not just by shape. I also bought two as suggested, but of different materials.
So in conclusion, here is a potential guide if you find yourself in the same situation:

Preliminary knowledge:

Fabrication: hangers can be forged or machined, forging is cheaper so manufacturers will also use cheaper alloys resulting in weaker hangers, machining is more expensive meaning the manufacturer will have little reason to use cheaper alloys resulting in stronger/stiffer hangers. A stiffer hanger seems to improve shifting according to a quick search online (probably plenty of questions answered about this already) but a hanger that is too strong may break the frame instead of itself in case of failure, so choose carefully.
Numbering: be aware that frame and hanger manufacturers will use different numbering for the same shape/hanger-model
Machining Manufacturers: Wheels Mfg (Wheels Manufacturing, 600+ models) in the US, BETD in the UK (~200 models), Pilo (500+ models, pilo.co.il)
Forging Manufacturers: XLC (~30 models), Union by Marwi (200+ models, but be aware that all websites I have seen will use either Union or Marwi as name but not both)
Measurements: 50factory.de and pjeker.ch in addition provide the measurements of the hangers in the pictures which the manufacturers do not


Search Guide:

Try searching your bike model in Wheels, Pilo or Marwi. To search all at the same time you can try ElanusParts.com, which seems to have the largest collection of all with over 1700 hangers from the various manufacturers.
If you cannot find it, filter by number of fasteners and look for a fitting shape, try Wheels or Pilo first to see if it even exists because they have the largest selection
Once you found the part, search for it at 50factory.com or pjeker.ch to get the measurements and verify the fitting
Go hunt for the best price and make your choice, once you know what to search for you will hopefully find one brand or the other everywhere (including Amazon, eBay, etc, indeed ElanusParts selss on Amazon too)



In my case all except XLC have my model (Wheels 41, BETD 41, Pilo D225, Marwi GH-200), ElanusParts is seelling Wheels, Pilo and Marwi for the cheapest price (with Pilo a bit cheaper than Wheels), but bikeINN had Marwi and Pilo at the same price with cheaper shipping, so I bought from bikeINN.

You can estimate measurements quite accurately from the photo because the derailleur bolt is 10mm and the picture is usually taken square-on. Nearly all hangers are some standard. Many of these bikes from so many manufacturers are/were produced in just a few Taiwanese factories and the dropout&hanger would be bought in from another factory specializing in this component to be welded into the frame. It is why so many different manufacturers seem to use the same hangers, otherwise unrelated to each other.

I think it is nice to support your local manufacturer if the quality is good. The machined ones are often more durable. Some cast ones are too soft and bend far too easily.

true, you can measure it from the picture if you can't find it online, but it's also nice that someone has done the job already for most of them

On many hanger manufacturer's websites, you can filter by number of fastners. In this case : one.
That narrows it down to 280 possibilities or so.
I have used wheelsmfg here

It looks like you need hanger 41 or 42. Buy both and send one back?
Looking a 2nd time, 41 is your match.
BETD in the UK use the same numbering scheme.
Other manufacturers use different identifying schemes.

If it is a bike you intend to keep for a while order 2 it can't hurt to have a spare.
